# Changes not update for schema.xml on SharePoint hosted app update

Tags: list, upgrade, sharepoint-hosted-app, elements-xml, schema

I have done my changes in my list's **schema.xml**. I have added extra view over existing list. I have also publish my app earlier but when I update my app over existing one it will reflect all changes like **JS, CSS** but changes from list's **schema.xml is not updating**.

Also data added in **lists element.xml is get duplicated on each update**.

Suggest any help.

Comment: Please check it after deleting your list and upload new app.

Comment: why should I delete a list? I just want to update my code over existing one